# C# Foreach loop through json-object, get key

Tags: c#, json, foreach, json.net

So my json looks like this:

```
{
     "hello1": 1.0,
     "hello2": 1.3,
     "hello3": 4.0,
}
```

Now i want to loop through the object and get the key and the value as a string.

This is how far i got:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(/*JSON*/); // load json
            foreach (var item in json)
            {...}
```

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end after 4.0.  What else are you having problems with?

Comment: Does `string key = item.Name;` and `string value = item.Value` inside `foreach` work?

Comment: It doesn't work @granit